# GDB cannot exec my test program

Tags: shell, gdb, exec

My computer run with Ubuntu 14.04. GDB seems to be abnormal in different account. For example I make a very simple test. I write a file under `~/test/test.c` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("hello,world");
    return 0;
}
```

and build with command **"gcc -g test.c -o test"**, then I get result file named test.
Next step, run gdb to debug. Notice that current account is user of my own.

```
$gdb test
(gdb)l      //work well
(gdb) b 6   //work well
(gdb) r     //error: Cannot exec /home/xxx/test/test -c exec /home/xxx/test/test .
            //Error: No such file or directory
```

But if I change to root account by command "su", gdb works well.
Why?

Comment: 2018 gdb still has that problem, shows in ddd too. you may need to place export SHELL at the top of .bashrc rather than the bottom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that your SHELL variable is set to a file that doesn't exist.  Try the following:

```
export SHELL=/bin/sh
gdb test
```

ensuring that `/bin/sh` exists and is executable.  This works via `su` not because of root permissions, but because `su` resets the `SHELL` environment variable. Per the [su manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/su.1.html):

> Note that the default behavior for the environment is the following:
>
> The $HOME, $SHELL, $USER, $LOGNAME, $PATH, and $IFS environment variables are reset.

### Further Discussion

If you are asking yourself, "How was I supposed to know that from the following error message?":

```
//error: Cannot exec /home/xxx/test/test -c exec /home/xxx/test/test .
//Error: No such file or directory
```

You are not alone.  This appears to be poor error reporting from `gdb`.  When `gdb` decides that it needs to execute your command using a shell, it constructs a command in the following format:

```
/path/to/shell -c exec /path/to/executable
```

However, when it prints the error message, it does this:

```
  save_errno = errno;
  fprintf_unfiltered (gdb_stderr, "Cannot exec %s", exec_file);
  for (i = 1; argv[i] != NULL; i++)
    fprintf_unfiltered (gdb_stderr, " %s", argv[i]);
  fprintf_unfiltered (gdb_stderr, ".\n");
  fprintf_unfiltered (gdb_stderr, "Error: %s\n",
                      safe_strerror (save_errno));
  gdb_flush (gdb_stderr);
```

Here `exec_file` is the expanded path of the file you passed on the command line.  It prints `exec_file` first, followed by the elements of `argv`, starting at the 1st index.  `argv` contains the arguments it passed to `execvp`.

Unfortunately, the shell it is trying to use is in the 0th element of `argv`, which never gets printed.  Thus, you never see the file that `execvp` couldn't find.

Further, it then prints a trailing `.` which isn't actually one of the arguments that it passed to `execvp` and is presumably there to make the message a completely sentence.

Finally, it prints the error we got back from our call to `execvp`, which is that the executable file could not be found.

This bug likely is caused by the fact that this error handling code is the same for the case where `gdb` attempts to exec the command directly and for the case when it uses the shell.  In the former case, the constructed error message would look correct since `exec_file` and `argv[0]` would be the same.

Comment: Why does it need to use the shell to execute the command?

Comment: @Barmar It doesn't *need* to, but it does so to make it easier for the user.  For instance, it allows you to specify command arguments that can be expanded by the shell (for instance globs such as * in paths).  In gdb 7.7 or greater, `set startup-with-shell false` will tell gdb to exec your program directly.  In versions older than that, it is a compile-time option.